# Akka Distributed Pub/Sub back-pressure

Tags: java, akka, publish-subscribe, akka-stream, akka-cluster

I am using Akka Distributed Pub/Sub and have a single publisher and a subscriber. My publisher is way faster than the subscriber. Is there a way to slow down the publisher after a certain point?

Publisher code:

```
public class Publisher extends AbstractActor {
    private ActorRef mediator;

    static public Props props() {
        return Props.create(Publisher.class, () -> new Publisher());
    }

    public Publisher () {
        this.mediator = DistributedPubSub.get(getContext().system()).mediator();
        this.self().tell(0, ActorRef.noSender());
    }

    @Override
    public Receive createReceive() {
        return receiveBuilder()
            .match(Integer.class, msg -> {
                // Sending message to Subscriber
                mediator.tell(
                    new DistributedPubSubMediator.Send(
                        "/user/" + Subscriber.class.getName(),
                        msg.toString(),
                        false),
                    getSelf());

                getSelf().tell(++msg, ActorRef.noSender());
            })
            .build();
    }
}
```

Subscriber code:

```
public class Subscriber extends AbstractActor {
    static public Props props() {
        return Props.create(Subscriber.class, () -> new Subscriber());
    }

    public Subscriber () {
        ActorRef mediator = DistributedPubSub.get(getContext().system()).mediator();
        mediator.tell(new DistributedPubSubMediator.Put(getSelf()), getSelf());
    }

    @Override
    public Receive createReceive() {
        return receiveBuilder()
            .match(String.class, msg -> {
                System.out.println("Subscriber message received: " + msg);
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            })
            .build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, as currently designed, I don't think that there is a way to provide "back-pressure" to the original Sender.  Since you are using [`ActorRef.tell`](https://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/current/index.html?akka/actor/package-summary.html&_ga=2.162752828.1823666753.1512998184-723935664.1469018756) to send the message to the `mediator` there is no way to get a signal that the downstream receiver is backing up.  This is because `tell`, the method you are using, returns a `void`.

**Switch To Ask**

If you switch your `tell` to an [`ask`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/actors.html#ask-send-and-receive-future) you can set an appropriate `Timeout` value that will at least let you know when you don't receive a response within a particular duration.

**Switch To Streams**

["Back-pressure" is a primary feature of akka streams](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-flows-and-basics.html#back-pressure-explained).  Therefore, by switching to a stream implementation you will be able to achieve your desired goal.

If it possible to create a stream [`Source`](https://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/current/index.html?akka/stream/package-summary.html&_ga=2.127858445.1856030509.1512998612-723935664.1469018756) from your original data, then you could use [`Sink.actorRef`](https://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/current/index.html?akka/stream/package-summary.html&_ga=2.127858445.1856030509.1512998612-723935664.1469018756) to create a `Sink` from the `mediator` and use [Flow.throttle](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4.11/index.html#akka.stream.javadsl.Flow@throttle(elements:Int,per:scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration,maximumBurst:Int,mode:akka.stream.ThrottleMode):akka.stream.javadsl.Flow[In,Out,Mat]) to control the rate of flow to the mediator.